# Retrieve some emails from Gmail to Mac Mail

Tags: gmail, email, mac

Somehow I have lost one month's worth of emails in my Mac Mail account after a drive failed.  (I lost September, though I have August and October.)  I do however have a copy of them in my Gmail account (used only for safety purposes).

Is there a way to download emails from September from Gmail and get them back into my Mac Mail account?

I have Mavericks.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the mails from your Gmail and import it to your mac mails

- **create a label like "September mails"**
- **Move all september mails to your label**
- **Go to your account settings**

[image]

**Data tool > Select data to download**

[image]

> Choose your label and download the mails

[image]

[The data is exported in standard, widely supported formats—MBOX for e-mail. Most e-mail clients and services can read these files](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/12/google-announces-data-export-feature-for-gmail-google-calendar-data/). From [Apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14911):

> **Mail (Mavericks): Import mailboxes**
>
> Mail can import messages from other email apps or from mailboxes that you exported using Mail.
>
> - Choose File > Import Mailboxes.
> - Select the email app you want to import messages from.
>
>   If you’re importing a mailbox exported from Mail, or a folder (such as POP-eharrold@mail.example.com) from the ~/Library/Mail/V2 folder on another Mac, choose Apple Mail.Follow the instructions that appear.
> - Make sure the app you’re importing from is active, because some of
>     the options require this.
> - If you’re importing messages from a Windows or UNIX computer, select
>     “Files in mbox format,” then locate the folder containing the files.
> - If the email app you’re switching from isn’t listed, click Cancel.
>     Consult the documentation for the other app to learn how to export
>     messages in mbox format (most email apps can). Then import the mbox
>     files.
> - Review and reorganize the imported messages.
>     The messages are located in a new mailbox called “Import” in the
>     sidebar. To reorganize the messages, create new mailboxes and drag
>     folders and messages from the Import mailbox to other mailboxes. When
>     you’re done, you can delete the Import mailbox.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed support.  I'll give it a try!

Comment: Ok.I have tried it and it works fine.